# Hive : Cannot INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE from unpartitioned External Table into a new partitioned table

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, hiveql

**In summary this is what I did**:

Original data -> SELECT and save filtered data in HDFS -> create an External table using the file saved in HDFS -> populate an empty table using the External table.

Looking at the Exception, seems this has something todo with OUTPUT types between the two tables

**In details** :

1) I have "table_log" table with lots of data (in Database A) with the following structure  (with 3 partitions) :

```
CREATE TABLE `table_log`(
  `e_id` string, 
  `member_id` string, 
  .
  .
PARTITIONED BY ( 
  `dt` string, 
  `service_type` string, 
  `event_type` string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\u0001' 
  COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY '\u0002' 
  MAP KEYS TERMINATED BY '\u0003' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat'
```

2) I filtered data by (td,service_type,event_type) and saved the result in HDFS as follows :

```
INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY  '/user/atscale/filterd-ratlog' SELECT * FROM rat_log WHERE dt >= '2016-05-01' AND dt <='2016-05-31' AND service_type='xxxx_jp' AND event_type='vv';
```

3) Then I created an **External Table** (table_log_filtered_ext) (in Database B) with above result.
Note that this table doesn't have the partitions.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_log_filtered_ext;
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `table_log_filtered_ext`(
  `e_id` string, 
  `member_id` string, 
  .
  .
  dt string,
  service_type string,
  event_type string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\u0001' 
  COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY '\u0002' 
  MAP KEYS TERMINATED BY '\u0003'
LOCATION '/user/atscale/filterd-ratlog'
```

4) I created another new table (table_log_filtered) similar to the "table_log" structure(with 3 partitions) as :

```
CREATE TABLE `table_log_filtered` (
  `e_id` string, 
  `member_id` string, 
  .
  .
PARTITIONED BY ( 
  `dt` string, 
  `service_type` string, 
  `event_type` string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\u0001' 
  COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY '\u0002' 
  MAP KEYS TERMINATED BY '\u0003' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat'
```

5) Now I wanted to populate "table_log_filtered" table (with 3 partitions as in "table_log") from the data from the external table "table_log_filtered_ext"

```
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
SET hive.execution.engine=tez; 

INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE rat_log_filtered PARTITION(dt, service_type, event_type) 
SELECT * FROM table_log_filtered_ext;
```

But I get this "java.lang.ClassCastException.
Looking at the exception, this has something todo with OUTPUT types between the two tables..
AnyTips ?:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row (tag=0) {"key":{},"value":
.
.
.
      at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:173)
      at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.run(TezProcessor.java:139)
      at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.run(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:344)
      at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable$1.run(TezTaskRunner.java:181)
      at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable$1.run(TezTaskRunner.java:172)
      at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
      at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
      at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
      at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable.callInternal(TezTaskRunner.java:172)
      at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable.callInternal(TezTaskRunner.java:168)
      at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row (tag=0
      at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.ReduceRecordSource$GroupIterator.next(ReduceRecordSource.java:370)
      at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.ReduceRecordSource.pushRecord(ReduceRecordSource.java:292)
      ... 16 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.io.Text cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde$OrcSerdeRow
      at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat$OrcRecordWriter.write(OrcOutputFormat.java:81)
      at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator.process(FileSinkOperator.java:753)
      at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:838)
      at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.LimitOperator.process(LimitOperator.java:54)
      at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:838)
      at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator.process(SelectOperator.java:88)
      at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.ReduceRecordSource$GroupIterator.next(ReduceRecordSource.java:361)
      ... 17 more
```

Comment: would you please try and check if the error persists with `SET hive.execution.engine=mr;`

Comment: yes..less stack-trace with MR, but seems like the same error. I think this has something todo with the OUTPUT types between the two tables ?

Comment: ORC is a complex **columnar** format, and the CREATE script should only specify `STORED AS ORC`. Because `ROW FORMAT DELIMITED` simply makes no sense *(applies only to **row** formats such as TextFile and SequenceFile)*, and only masochists use `INPUTFORMAT` and `OUTPUTFORMAT` clauses when the SerDe is fully defined by its alias.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case if anyone else bump into this issue, the fix was as @Samson Scharfrichter mentioned , I specified STORED AS ORC for the table_log_filtered

```
CREATE TABLE `table_log_filtered` (
  `e_id` string, 
  `member_id` string, 
  .
  .
PARTITIONED BY ( 
  `dt` string, 
  `service_type` string, 
  `event_type` string)
STORED AS ORC
```

Comment: Pleeeease, drop also the `ROW FORMAT DELIMITED` section that makes no sense for ORC. At best, it is completely ignored; at worst, it could have nasty side effects -- as you have experienced with your initial attempt with `OUTPUTFORMAT`.